# CubeCamera with BoxGeometry

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use CubeCamera with BoxGeometry, but the rendering is distorted.
How can I make to leave in the same way as the original sphere? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it illusion? It seems to me to be bigger.

Comment: You might want to use the following example as a code template: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic.html

Comment: yes! thanks Mugen!

Comment: I put:
cubeCamera1.position.y -= Math.abs(camera.position.y - (plane.position.y));
works, thanks!

Comment: Mugen,
when I use a cube to reflect or refraction with CubeCamera
and I distanced myself. distorts because the reflection is seted in envMap and it's fixed.
is there any way to put depth in envmap?